# Communication link failure: Spring boot, MySQL, Docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I have a microservice arhitecture and each microservice has it's own mysql database. The application works fine in an IDE but i have problems deploying it because I can't bind my mysql db to game microservice. I'm getting Communication link failure. Stack trace is below.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  # Database
  game-mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: game-mysql-db
    hostname: mysql-game
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'boardify_game_development'
      MYSQL_USER: 'Boardify'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'boardify'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    networks:
      - boardify-app-network

  # Core services
  service-discovery:
    hostname: service-discovery
    image: eureka-server
    container_name: service-discovery
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - boardify-app-network


  boardify-game-service:
    build:
      context: ./game
      args:
        JAR_FILE: game-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: game
    container_name: boardify-game-service
    hostname: boardify-game-service
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      - boardify-app-network
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8083
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://service-discovery:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://game-mysql-db:3306/boardify_game_development
    depends_on:
      - game-mysql-db

networks:
  boardify-app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

application-production.properties

```
#tomcat properties
server.port=8083
#logging file properties
logging.file.path=./logs
logging.file.name=${logging.file.path}/game.log
#application properties
spring.application.name=game-service
#liquibase properties
#database properties
spring.datasource.url=@game.db.url@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=@db.driverClassName@
spring.datasource.username=@db.username@
spring.datasource.password=@db.password@
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
#jpa properties
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=@sql.dialect@

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=30

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=30
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=60
security.jwt.url=/authenticate/login
security.jwt.header=Authorization
security.jwt.header.prefix=Bearer
security.jwt.expiration=1800000
security.jwt.secret=securitysecret23992_2332

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://service-discovery:8761/eureka
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>prod</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <game.db.url>jdbc:mysql://game-mysql-db:3306/boardify_game_development</game.db.url>
                <db.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClassName>
                <sql.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</sql.dialect>              
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</settings>
```

Stack trace:

```
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:40.932  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct ins
tantiation.
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:42.164 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20e93c44.getConnection(<generated>) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:311) [liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.R
ELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELE
ASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE
]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE
]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at boardify.game.GameApplication.main(GameApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      ... 50 common frames omitted
boardify-game-service    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      ... 53 common frames omitted
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:42.186  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguratio
n.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:42.210  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:42.429  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
boardify-game-service    | 2020-05-17 08:19:42.467 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseA
utoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link fa
ilure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.REL
EASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEAS
E]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]

boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE
]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at boardify.game.GameApplication.main(GameApplication.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [game.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
boardify-game-service    | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    |      at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.
RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.REL
EASE]
boardify-game-service    |      ... 26 common frames omitted
boardify-game-service    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
boardify-game-service    |
boardify-game-service    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
boardify-game-service    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]

boardify-game-service exited with code 1
service-discovery        | 2020-05-17 08:19
```

Comment: it clearly says the driver is missing - Hence the chances are that you have not built the application correctly or you added the driver jar from some location in your machine which is not accessible by the Docker

Comment: @AbhishekKothari that line is printed even when it works. This is printed without docker: 2020-05-17 17:07:52.199  WARN 16380 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-05-17 17:07:52.720  INFO 16380 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this issue for a full week of pain I have unexpectedly solved this. I've added this 3 lines of code in game's environment (docker-compose).

```
  - spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:mysql://game-mysql-db:3306/boardify_game_development
  - spring.liquibase.user=Boardify
  - spring.liquibase.password=boardify
```

I had the url set only for spring_datasource_url.
I was setting them in application.properties but it looks like i must set them in environment.